# vuejs: SCSS @import ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, sass, vue.js

I'm using VueJS for two projects, and have been very satisfied generally.

Now, I'm about to go live, and am trying to generate the files using `npm run build` (I started both projects from the VueJS Webpack Simple template).

One project, which is a fairly recent one, worked as expected. The other one, which was initiated in May, does not, however, giving a bunch of deprecation errors that didn't show up when running `npm run dev`.

After having updated all the dependencies and configs, I almost got it working again. However, now, all the `@import`-tags are ignored, effectively throwing away all my SCSS.

I don't get an error - the rendered content simply is not there. The JS is rendered properly.

I wish I could give more information, but I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I'm not very used to working with Webpack, and I assume the imports are simply optimized away somewhere.

Both projects use SCSS and have the same loader config.

If I set the `@import` paths to erroneous ones, I get import errors:

```
@import "./sass/_invalid_/forms";
^
File to import not found or unreadable: ./sass/_invalid_/forms.
```

So it's obviously reading the files correctly, but I get no output.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you change anything in your webpack-config for prod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue arose when I upgraded `vue-loader` to version `12.1.0`. I downgraded to `11.3.4` in my `package.json`, which solved my issue.